# Postgresql - How to change JSONB data type?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table which includes jsonb column "details" with wrong data type as follow:

```
select id,details from products;

id |              details                
---+-----------------------------------------
 1 | {"price": "310", "supplier": "VendorA"}
 2 | {"price": "250", "supplier": "VendorB"}
```

Here I would like to change data type of "price" to integer which is stored as string currently. Desired result is as follows:

```
id |              details             
---+-----------------------------------------
 1 | {"price": 310, "supplier": "VendorA"}
 2 | {"price": 250, "supplier": "VendorB"}
```

I will appreciate if you can guide me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the value to json number using the function `to_jsonb()`:

```
select id, jsonb_set(details, '{price}', to_jsonb((details->>'price')::int))
from products

 id |               jsonb_set               
----+---------------------------------------
  1 | {"price": 310, "supplier": "VendorA"}
  2 | {"price": 250, "supplier": "VendorB"}
(2 rows)
```

The update statement may look like this:

```
update products
set details = jsonb_set(details, '{price}', to_jsonb((details->>'price')::int))
```